# Related Rates problem with two circles

Tags: calculus

How could a model be made for this problem?  I tried playing around with the radius and trying to find some way to model the distance between them at 100 metres while getting 15 metres/hour included somehow but I am stumped.

> Two mice are running on circular tracks, with one lap being 500 metres. The tracks are 40 metres apart and the mice start opposite each other on the inside of the tracks and run at the same rate of 15 metres/hour. How fast are the mice separating when each has run 100 metres?

Comment: in which direction are the mice running ? - if one is clockwise and the other counter clockwise they will crash when they come to the first intersection !

Comment: They are on different circles.  picture two plates spaced apart with the mouse on the circumference of the left plate running counter clockwise and the mouse on the right plate running clockwise.  They start at the same point, which is where they're closest and then proceed to run

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way to do this problem would be to choose an origin ($O$) at the point equidistant from the two mice ($A$, $B$) at their initial positions, which passes through the two centers ($C_1$, $C_2$) of the circles. This line would be $\overline{C_1 O C_2}$

The distance between each mouse and the origin ($\overline{OA}$ and $\overline{OB}$) should be easy to calculate using trigonometry and modelling them as points moving with some angular velocity around a circle. The distance between them is always the line $\overline{AB}$ (which passes through $O$), and if you find the rate of change of either of them, you have the rate of change of the other.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Why is it that finding the rate of change for either  $\overline{OA}$  or $\overline{OB}$ would give you the rate of change of $\overline{AB}$, which is what the question is asking for?  I've made a sketch and I can't find any relation between $\overline{OA}$ and $\overline{AB}$, which would allow me to begin differentiating.  I seem to require angles in order to get any sort of relation between the lengths but doing so seems to require the introduction of a new variable

Comment: $\overline{OA}$ = $\overline{OB}$ = $\frac{1}{2} \overline{AB}$. Imagine you were at the point where the 'left' mouse was at the top of the left circle, and the 'right' mouse was on the bottom of the right circle. Connect their positions through the origin and you should see.